# JPA: Setting @JoinColumn(updatable = false) to avoid OptimisticLockException

Tags: java, jpa, optimistic-locking

Given the following the following two entities

```
@Entity
public class A {
  @Version
  protected int version;

  String basicPropertey;

  // getter and setter for basicProperty
}

@Entity
public class B {
  @Version
  protected int version;

  @ManyToOne
  private A a;

  public B(A a) {
    this.a = a}
  }

  //getter for a
}
```

Two questions:

1. Is there version number of the entity A increased every time the
   entity B is merged to the DB (note that there is no
   CascadeType.MERGE defined on the relationship to A) and, thus, cause
   a possible OptimisticcLockException when A is merged with a
   different version number?
2. If yes, would it help to avoid the likelihood of an
   OptimisticLockException if I add `@JoinColumn(updatable=false)` on the
   relationship?

My situation is that entity B is updated very frequently and A sporadically, but only its basic attributes (not the relationship) and I'm getting an OptimisticLockException on the entity A.

Comment: I'm not sure what locking type is the default one, but did you try fiddling with the Lock modes (`OPTIMISTIC` vs `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`)?

Comment: I think per default it's OPTIMISTIC. I think it's irrelevant here, since you can only specify the lock mode when you explicitly use the entity manager's lock API, which I don't. All I have is a @Version field.

Answer (score 1):

If you only change B, then you cannot get a lock error on A.

You will only get a lock error on B.

Check you SQL log to what you are actually doing.

Comment: B and A are updated. But the update in B does not touch its relationship A.